# Unable to getting the results from concurrent CompletionService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am very new to the Java concurrent package. I am using the **java.util.concurrent.CompletionService** class for getting the results from the pool without any waiting for the other threads to complete the task. But I was unable to get the tasks even after 10 min of code execution. I am just printing the thread name in the task. Here is my code.

```
public class CompletionService {

    public void execute(ThreadPoolExecutor argThreadPoolExecutor)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        java.util.concurrent.CompletionService<String> completionService = 
                 new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(argThreadPoolExecutor);
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Task task = new Task();
            completionService.submit(task);
            ++counter;
        }
        print(counter, completionService);
    }

    private void print(int argCounter,
            java.util.concurrent.CompletionService<String> argCompletionService)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        String s = argCompletionService.take().get();
        if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            ExecutionException {
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(8, 8,
                3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        CompletionService completionService = new CompletionService();
        completionService.execute(threadPoolExecutor);
        threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Task class:

```
public class Task implements Callable<String> {

@Override

    public String call() throws Exception {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Result:**
**pool-1-thread-1**

I am getting only one thread information. I waited 10-15 min still I am not getting the results. Am I wrong anywhere.? Can any one help me on this.?

Thanq.

Comment: So what were you expecting? Do you get result printed?

Comment: Yes. My Result looks like pool-1-thread-1, pool-1-thread-2,pool-1-thread-3,pool-1-thread-4. Because I am creating 4 tasks and I am expecting 4 print statements in output.

Comment: aren't you getting four thread names then?

Answer (score 3):

```
completionService.execute(threadPoolExecutor);
threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You will block here forever because you have not asked the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to [shutdown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown--).

Answer (score 1):

You're not looping in your `print(...)` method, so you're only ever taking the first result from the completion service.  Try this instead:

```
private void print(int argCounter, CompletionService<String> argCompletionService) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    for (int i = 0; i < argCounter; i++) {
        String s = argCompletionService.take().get();
        if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) 
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Also you're not [shutting down](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) your [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).  This will mean that your program will never finish. Add a call to [`shutdown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) after your task submission loop.

Comment: Thanq Jamie. Its just my sample code. But I am facing another issue in this. In the "ExecutorCompletionService<V>" it has a method called "done()" and in that method its adding all the tasks into "completionQueue". When I debug this code this queue getting increased and I am not getting the output. Is it a normal behaviour (The queue size got increased).? 

Finally, I am not getting my output from the "CompletionService".

Can you please explain why I am facing this issue.?